# Getting error "Got minus one from a read call, connect lapse 4 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms." connecting to Oracle image on docker

Tags: oracle, docker

When I try to connect to a oracle in a docker container, from Oracle SQL Developer,
I get the error "Got minus one from a read call, connect lapse 4 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms."

I went on the oracle container page https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:10::::::

I pulled express version, I was going to pull the standard but its been removed.

```
docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:latest
```

I then ran the image

```
docker run --name oracle-container -p 1521:5500 -e ORACLE_PWD=MyPasswd123 -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 -v /opt/oracle/oradata container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:latest
```

Got database started, and then logged in on the command line

```
docker exec -it oracle-container sqlplus sys/MyPasswd123@//localhost:1521/xe as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Dec 11 10:49:14 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

Ran a command no problem

```
SQL> SELECT sys_context('userenv','instance_name') FROM dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XE
```

The problem is trying to connect from java or from Oracle SQL Developer

I set username as sys as sysdba
password as MyPasswd123@
HostName as localhost
port as 1521
SID as XE

And I get the error.
Its confusing as I can connect, using the command line docker exec -it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding enterprise manager (port 5500) to host port 1521.

```
# fire up the database
docker run --name oracle-container -d --rm -p 1521:5500 -e ORACLE_PWD=MyPasswd123 -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8  container-registry.oracle.c
om/database/express:latest

# query from inside the container
echo 'select dummy from dual;' | docker container exec -i oracle-container sqlplus -S system/MyPasswd123@localhost:1521/XE

D
-
X

# query from outside the container 
echo 'select dummy from dual;' | sqlplus -S system/MyPasswd123@localhost:1521/XE
ERROR:
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed

# let's bind to the correct port
docker run --name oracle-container -d --rm -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_PWD=MyPasswd123 -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8  container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:latest

# query from inside the container
echo 'select dummy from dual;' | docker container exec -i oracle-container sqlplus -S system/MyPasswd123@localhost:1521/XE

D
-
X

# query from outside the container. This time it works!
echo 'select dummy from dual;' | sqlplus -S system/MyPasswd123@localhost:1521/XE

D
-
X
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may also may need to simply give it a little extra time. I wasn't waiting long enough for the database to start.

You may be able to monitor logs with the container you're using `container-registry.oracle.com/database/express`.

```
docker logs -f oracle-container
```

Also may want to check out this container `gvenzl/oracle-xe` which is working for me: https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe